# Questions about GWT module file

Tags: gwt

For GWT module file, it is used in the compilation or it is used in the run-time or both?

Also for the GWT locale, I define the following

```
  <extend-property name="locale" values="nl"/>
  <extend-property name="locale" values="en"/> 
  <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

and I have one java class MyMessages.java (no default value is define in the class), which extends gwt client.Message package, I also have two properties file: MyMessages_nl.properties and MyMessages_en.properties. I don't define MyMessages.properties file.

When I compile the application, error always occurs, it seems like when the GWT compiler can't find the default properties file for MyMessages.java, it doesn't fall back to MyMessages_en.properties. Does anybody know why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5769

The workaround is to add:

```xml
<set-property name="locale" value="nl,en" />
```

so that there's no longer a `locale=default` permutation.